# Disabling/overriding highlighting on WPF controls

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, overlay

I have a RichTextBox with ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility=Auto, and this is working just like I want it to. However, when I hover my mouse over the document I get a blue border around the entire RichTextBox element and the only way I can seem to make it go away is by setting IsHitTestVisible=false, but if I do that the scroll bar becomes disabled too... Other things I've tried is IsFocusable=false and making a trigger for the RichTextBox's style, without any success:

```xml
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

I have the same problem with images in my application that are displayed in a ListBox. I have a ListBox looking like this:

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Photos}"
         BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPhoto, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True" 
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                         Columns="3" Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" 
                   Stretch="Uniform" 
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                                 Color="Transparent"/>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Brush_Secondary}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Brush_Primary}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Brush_Selected}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

But no matter which colors I use (Brush_Primary/Secondary/Selected) the border is always just different shades of blue... How do I get rid of this blue overlay/highlight thing that seems to exist for every single WPF control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the `RichTextBox template` to remove the default value -

```
<Style TargetType="RichTextBox">
   <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border x:Name="Bd"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ScrollViewer Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a hardcore necro response, but this removed just the border.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type RichTextBox}" TargetType="RichTextBox">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Of course, you can set the key to whatever you want. But this is what removed that border for me without overriding the style.